# Lightning: Set child controller from parent

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Is it possible to set child controller from parent?

Child.cmp

```
<aura:component> ... </aura:component>
```

Parent.cmp

```
<aura:component>
 <c:Child controller="TestController" />
</aura:component>
```

Comment: [Data Binding Between Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_data_binding.htm)

Comment: Not directly, because the controller attribute doesn't support expressions, and is validated against existing classes during compilation. This is kind of an [x-y question](http://xyproblem.info). Try making an [edit] to ask about the problem you are trying to solve, and let us provide a solution for you.